# How do I handle response errors using with Retrofit and RxJava/RxAndroid?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I am having trouble working out how to handle a response error with retrofit and RxAndroid. onError() gets called if there is a network error or the like but I need to be able to get the response to check if there was an authentication error. Instead what I get is a token with a null String and I can't find out why. What is the best way to go about this?

This is my RxAndroid call at the moment.

```
    Client.getInstance().getService()
            .getToken(usernameET.getText().toString(), passwordET.getText().toString())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<SiteInfo>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(SiteInfo siteInfo) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onNext "+ token.toString());
                }
            });
```

This is my retrofit service

```
@GET("my_url_here")
Observable<Token> getToken(
        @Query("username") String username,
        @Query("password") String password
);
```

This is my Current restadapter

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .build();

service = restAdapter.create(MyService.class);
```

And this is my Token Class.

```
public class Token {
    private String token;

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return token;
    }
}
```

How should I go about handlng this. Can it be done in the RxAndroid part or do I need to add something to my RestClient or maybe something else entirely?

Thanks.

**Edit**

```
07-01 06:38:04.562    1680-1793/uk.co.dyolo.thing D/Retrofit﹕ ---> HTTP GET my_website_here
07-01 06:38:04.562    1680-1793/uk.co.dyolo.thing D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP (no body)
07-01 06:38:04.610    1680-1793/uk.co.dyolo.thing D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 200 my_website_here (48ms)
07-01 06:38:04.610    1680-1793/uk.co.dyolo.thing D/Retrofit﹕ : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: What is `authentication error`? Retrofit's observable emits error if there was status other than `200`.

Comment: Unfortunately the server doesn't give a status code. `{"error":"The username was not found in the database","stacktrace":null,"debuginfo":null,"reproductionlink":null}` is the response I get.

Comment: The server gives you status. Status codes is a part of `http`.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I get what you mean. The server must be giving me a `200` code then, which isn't very helpful.

Comment: I think he is implying that the server sends him 200. But the response contains the error string. In that case, you really can't blame retrofit for this. Ask the module owner to send the error code in response like 500 etc or handle it yourself by parsing the JSON and checking whether error!=null.

Comment: I unfortunately won't be able to get the module owner to change the server code. I am currently working on something that might work, if it does I will post  my solution.

Comment: @Radther enable logs in retorfit and post full answer of the server. Not just the body.

Comment: I have added the response I get back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## I have found a solution

Firstly I expanded my Token object to have an error property.

```
public class Token {

    private String token;
    private String error;

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return token;
    }
}
```

Then I added an operator to my RxJava chain which can check to see if the error field is not `null`. And if there is an error, throw a custom exception which calls the subscribers `onError` allowing me to handle it.

```
if (token.getError() != null) {
    throw OnErrorThrowable.from(new UserAuthenticationException(token.getError()));
    }
```

And if there is an error, throw a custom exception which calls the subscribers `onError` allowing me to handle it.

```
if (e instanceof OnErrorThrowable){
    if (e.getCause() instanceof UserAuthenticationException){
        Log.d(TAG, "onError "+e.getCause().getMessage());
    }
    e.getCause().printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us what is the operator you add in the RxJava chain ;) I am doing the same thing than you, and I would like to factorize the error-check somewhere. I am currently using `.flatMap(...)` which is not so "beautiful".

Comment: @mithrop I believe I just used a map operator and if there was an error, I throw the exeaption, otherwise, I just returned the object. So in this case, map<Token, Token>.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late but if anyone wanders here, Retrofit 2 passes in instance of `HttpException` into the `onError` callback whenever the request returned from the server with an error code outside the [200,300) interval ...

```
throwable -> {
    if(throwable instanceof HttpException){
        switch(((HttpException)throwable).code()){
            // your error handling logic 
        }
    }
}
```

You can also retrieve the whole reponse from this object..