# Retrofit/RxJava - get http response code

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, http-error

Android, Retrofit, RxJava. Please look at this example call:

```
 mcityService.signOut(signOutRequest)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(resp ->
                {
                    busyIndicator.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }, throwable ->
                {
                    Log.d(tag, throwable.toString());
                    busyIndicator.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(this,throwable.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                });
```

Does anybody know how to get error code (as error number) from throwable? I am able to get full stacktrace or message (as shown above). How to capture error code?

Error code from throwable:
[image]

Comment: Please look at my screenshot from debug. There is `code` field, but not accesible

Comment: apart form the answers check the comment by jake @ https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1218 which means any non 200 errors can be handled in `onNex`t with ` Observable<Response<Type>>` or `Observable<Result<Type>>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use casting??

```
mcityService.signOut(signOutRequest)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(resp ->
                {
                    busyIndicator.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }, throwable ->
                {
                    Log.d(tag, throwable.toString());
                    Log.d(code, ((HttpException)throwable).code());

                    busyIndicator.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(this,throwable.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                });
```

Comment: Also need to check if `throwable` is actually instance of `HttpException`. For example, if there is no network available, it's not and app will crash

Comment: use instanceOf of your throwable

Answer (score 3):

[Retrofit 2 + Rxjava handling error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144954/retrofit-2-rxjava-handling-error) here is your answer

```
                @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                if (e instanceof HttpException) {
                    ResponseBody body = ((HttpException) e).response().errorBody();

                    Converter<ResponseBody, Error> errorConverter =
                        application.getRetrofit().responseBodyConverter(Error.class, new Annotation[0]);
                // Convert the error body into our Error type.
                    try {
                        Error error = errorConverter.convert(body);
                        Log.i("","ERROR: " + error.message);
                        mLoginView.errorText(error.message);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                 }



            static class Error{
            String message;
            }
```

see [here](https://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2016-03-16-retrofit2-rxjava-error-handling.html) for more .

Comment: This really sucks. I wonder why just error code is not accesible from throwable, the same way as error message. Thanks for tip anyway