# How to use Retrofit's GsonConverter without passing-in an instance of Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-android, rx-java2

I am currently developing the error handling part of a Retrofit2 client (using Rx implementation of Retrofit).

After searching for a while, I cannot find a simple way to deserialize the ResponseBody returned by Retrofit into the POJO of my error.

I would love to use [one of the json converters supported by Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters) but everyone of them requires to pass-in an instance of the actual Retrofit class, which does not seem available inside my onError() callback.

Is there a way to provide "retrofit" from "onError()" callback ? Or even better, is there a way to make the deserialization without providing it ? I don't understand why this is needed.

If no, is my design bad ?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308910/rx-java-retrofit-2-error-handling/36329213#36329213) provides a way to get rid of it, but it does not work for me, I guess it is outdated.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144954/retrofit-2-rxjava-handling-error) uses a warkaround to access retrofit instant, I don't want that.

Otherwise, the other posts suggest to use their own parser and I don't really need that.

```
api.login(email, password)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Observer<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
            // Nothing to do
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(@NonNull LoginResponse loginResponse) {
            // Normal use case with 2xx http status
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
            // non-2xx http status handled here
            // This is what I tried
            if (e instanceof HttpException) {
                HttpException exception = (HttpException) e;
                Response response = exception.response();
                Converter<ResponseBody, LoginError> converter = GsonConverterFactory.create()                                      
                    .responseBodyConverter(LoginError.class, new Annotation[0], retrofit); //<--- How can I provide "retrofit" here ?
                LoginError error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
           // Nothing to do
        }
});
```

Comment: Why do you need `GsonConverterFactory` here? Just use `Gson`. This assumes that the `errorBody()` is actually JSON, of course.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's exactly what I needed thanks. Should I delete my question ?

Comment: I suggest answering your own question, showing what you did. That way, the question and the answer can help others in the future. Glad to hear that you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to use `Gson.fromJson()`, not `GsonConverter.responseBodyConverter()`.

I used the`response.errorBody().toString()` to get the JSON string to deserialize.

```
return new Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody().string(), LoginError.class);
```

Thanks to CommonsWare for pointing that out.